# how to diplay photos with same date in ListView in flutter

Tags: flutter

As you can see in Firestore there is a collection called Photos and all photos have a property called DateCreated, How we can just show photos with the same date in the listView?

Ps. I don't want to hardcode the date in the query : something like this `collection('photos).where('').isequalto('date')`

```
class SweetList extends StatefulWidget {
  const SweetList({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SweetList> createState() => _SweetListState();
}

class _SweetListState extends State<SweetList> {
  String transparentEmoji = 'assets/images/poo2.png';
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('photos')
      .orderBy('dateCreated')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
        stream: _photoStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                final data =
                    snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 20),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      dialog(context);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      height: 400,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('${data['imgUrl']}'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

[image]

How we can just show photos with the same date in the listView?

Comment: What do you mean by not hardcode the date? do you want it to load only for today date? or specific date?

Or you want to group the photos by date instead?

Comment: Hey Thanks or you time , As this  Listview is a child widget of Carsoule , and in every page of Carsould I want to display a specific day .

Answer (score 1):

I dont quite get your use case, but this might help with your need

1. Use grouped list - https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list

- query everything
- group them in list using grouped list by Date, you can see the screenshot for example

[image]

2. Create flow that user will have to select which date to filter - then query by the date selected by user. Its not hardcoding the date, but instead you will be passing dynamic date to the query
3. Change the query to group by default, but dont query all images at once, instead provide a date range for it

Comment: Hey , Ismi , Thanks didnt know about this package. Cheers . But prefet to  use dart and the logic than any third party package.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! I think it make sense to break down the problem into:

**1. Figure out what are all the unique dates.**
I am not sure you could get that directly from Firestore query, therefore I think you would just get all the documents first and then create a list of unique dates.

**2. Sort the items into unique date buckets.**

**3. Display the photos in each bucket.**
Now that yo have a list of unique dates you can then pick the unique date you want and sort the main list of photos for that date (or a list made up of unique dates and each unique date has list of photos)

```
 void main() {
photos.forEach((p) {

listOfDates.add(p.date);
});

uniquelistOfDates = listOfDates.toSet().toList();

print(uniquelistOfDates);
  
  
for (var d in uniquelistOfDates) {
  
  List<Photo> photosOnDate = [];
  
  for (var p in photos) {
    if (p.date == d) {
      photosOnDate.add(p);
    }
    
  }
    
    map[d] = photosOnDate;
  
}
  
  print(map);
 
  
}

Map map = Map<num, List<Photo>>();


List<num> listOfDates = [];
List<num> uniquelistOfDates = [];


class Photo{
String uid, imgURL;
num date;

Photo({ 
   required this.uid,
   required this.imgURL,
   required this.date
   });
}

List<Photo> photos = [

Photo(date: 160000, uid: "aaa", imgURL: "url1"),
Photo(date: 160000, uid: "bbb", imgURL: "url2"),
Photo(date: 170000, uid: "ccc", imgURL: "url3"),
Photo(date: 170000, uid: "ddd", imgURL: "url4"),
Photo(date: 180000, uid: "eee", imgURL: "url3"),
Photo(date: 180000, uid: "fff", imgURL: "url4"),

];
```

Comment: Hey Nick that's interesting ! , You solution made me think , What if i get all date from Firestore , and make them the key of the map and also photo urls as value, and then if the keys are the same (date ) get all the values which are the urls??

Comment: Hey, yeah for sure i think that is reasonable way to go! I updated my reply accordingly. This also avoids you having to read in the list of photos from Firebase more than once. I think with a list of all photos, list of unique dates, and map of {uniqueDate: [Photo, Photo...]} you will have lots of flexibility!